# expression resolves to an unused I-value during if statement

Tags: swift, button, ibaction, iboutlet

So I'm downloading a String from CloudKit, created here

```
let facebookurl = detail.value(forKey: "Facebook") as? String
```

I also have an outlet saved as `facebookbutton` and an action button set as `Facebook`.

I want to have my code set up as such that if facebookurl is empty "", the `facebookbutton` hides the actual button `facebook`, like such.

```
 if facebookurl == ""
    {
        facebookbutton.isHidden
    }
```

However, Xcode reverts me to the unused I-value error. What seems to be amish here?

Comment: you need to actually set the isHidden like `facebookbutton.isHidden = true`

Comment: bummer, I figured the ".hidden" was all I needed, haha. Adding the "= true" solved the error, I appreciate the assistance, Pierce!

Comment: Sure thing! I'll post an answer just in case anyone else comes by.

Comment: You'll get the check as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `isHidden` property for your button, but you're never assigning a value. You need to complete the process by setting the `isHidden` a value of either `true` or `false`:

```
if facebookurl == "" {

    facebookbutton.isHidden = true

}
```